# PyGame any touchscreen

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a simple program in which a user can move a shape on the screen using his finger (on a touchscreen).

this is my code so far:

```
import pygame


def main():
    pygame.init()
    DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,500),0,32)
    WHITE = (255,255,255)
    blue = (0,0,255)
    DISPLAY.fill(WHITE)
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY, blue,(480,200,50,250))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.mouse.set_pos(480, 200)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY, blue, (pos[0]-25,pos[1], 50, 250))
            pygame.display. update()
            DISPLAY.fill(WHITE)
main()
```

The problem is that when I touch the screen, nothing will happen until I move my finger. If I print the events I can see that there is no event listed until I start moving my finger, so that is probably the reason.

I want to be able to register the finger press (as an event I guess) on the screen even before it starts to move, is there anyway to do this using PyGame?

Thanks.

Comment: I don' know about touchscreen. But there is a keydown event if you control the game via the keyboard. Maybe there is something similar...

Answer (score 8):

In case anyone is stumbling across this later, in pygame 2 there is much better touch support. You can install with

```
pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6
```

(check the pygame github for the most recent version) And there are three new event types. `pygame.FINGERDOWN`, `pygame.FINGERUP`, and `pygame.FINGERMOTION`. The `pygame.FINGERUP` event registers the touch input right when the screen is touched instead of when the screen is released like `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`

Answer (score 5):

I have made a game that utilises a computer touch screen and manages the touch quite well by handling two types of events. One is `pygame.MOUSEMOTION` and the other one is `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`. Both of them contain the attribute `event.pos`. Problem is, at least when it comes to my touch screen (Lenovo), that the initial touch is not registered by the event handler of pygame.

You can confirm this by printing all the events to the terminal while touching your screen. I get nothing until I release or move my finger but on release I get the event `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` rapidly followed by `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP`.

I know that this doesn't really solve your problem, but it might perhaps help you in some way. Otherwise, check out [Kivy](https://kivy.org/). There might be a solution there.

```
import pygame

def main():
    pygame.init()
    DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,500),0,32)
    WHITE = (255,255,255)
    blue = (0,0,255)
    DISPLAY.fill(WHITE)
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY, blue,(480,200,50,250))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.mouse.set_pos(480, 200)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN or event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                pos = event.pos
            pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY, blue, (pos[0]-25,pos[1], 50, 250))
            pygame.display. update()
            DISPLAY.fill(WHITE)
main()
```